# How can a user disable google drive access for an app?

Tags: google-drive-api

In order for google drive api calls to work, a user must install the app through the Chrome Web Store. I would like to know how to undo this process for testing. I tried uninstalling our CWS app, but drive api calls are still going through just fine. Is there some additional step beyond uninstalling the app that's necessary?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can uninstall apps from Drive through the "Wheel" top right menu > Manage Apps... > Options > Remove this app.

If you just want to test the auth flow again (you know the first time you do open-with or create-new you go through the OAuth 2 grant screen) you can go to the following page https://accounts.google.com/IssuedAuthSubTokens .
It lets you revoke OAuth access to apps, if you revoke access to your app the next time you do open-with or create-new you will go through the OAuth 2 grant screen again.

(Very useful since only the first time you exchange the auth code will you get a refresh token)

I would usually do the later for development it's easier than uninstalling + reinstalling an app.

Comment: Great, this is useful info. It looks like removing an app from Drive without uninstalling it from the CWS gets the user into an awkward place where the only way to get the app back into Drive is to uninstall and then reinstall the CWS app, which is not so obvious. I know the team is looking at smoothing out the process for installing drive apps, so hopefully this case can get cleaned up too.

Comment: @Jason, Yes there is still lots of work to do to get the Chrome Web Store install/uninstall user experience right. We are aware of this and there is lots of work being done to improve things in that area. Cheers!